# Не могу устаноить Mongodb driver java

Tags: java, android, mongodb

Не могу устаноить библиотеку для подключения базы данных библиотека не jar.
платформа А-С
Кто может помоч а вот и сама библиотека
 [Библиотека драйверя для удаленного подключения](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases/tag/r3.4.0-rc1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `build.gradle` добавьте зависимость:

```
compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.4.0-rc1'
```

Comment: не моглиб дать ссылку на гайд по обьявлению написанию чтению данных по бд ,я немогу найти

Comment: @elik, [Getting started](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/java/client/), [JavaDoc](http://api.mongodb.com/java/).

Comment: это для клиенсткой базы а я спользую удаленно

Comment: через mlab.com что тогда

Comment: Тогда, наверное, можно воспользоваться конструктором `public MongoClient(final String host, final int port)` для создания экземпляра `MongoClient`.

Comment: гдето есть найд по удаленному упралению ? или исходинки какието экземпляры

Comment: Может где-то и есть. А исходники на [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) есть.

Comment: спасибо очень помогли